# mysql select row before max value

Tags: mysql, sql

My Requirement is to get the row before the `max(create_date)`.

```
SELECT servicecalls_servicecall_id, max(created_at) FROM 
service_followup_details  where servicecalls_servicecall_id IN (SELECT 
service_call_id from service_calls where status=2) group by 
servicecalls_servicecall_id
```

How can I do it by MySQL query?

Comment: What is your error ?

Comment: Sort the table on created_at desc and  use  ROW_NUMBER window function. 

Retrieve the row_number = 2

Answer (score 0):

Get the max(create_at), then pick the one which is less than that max value.

```
select servicecalls_servicecall_id,created_at 
from `service_followup_details` 
where created_at<(
    SELECT  max(created_at) 
    FROM `service_followup_details` 
    where servicecalls_servicecall_id IN 
        (SELECT service_call_id from service_calls 
        where status=2) 
    group by servicecalls_servicecall_id
    )
order by created_at desc 
limit 1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can achieve this with the help of [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/) function.
Check my implementation below. What I've done is, I'm sorting the records by `created_at` in a `DESC` order. Off course, this is partitioned by the `servicecalls_servicecall_id` so the sequence will restart for each new `servicecalls_servicecall_id`. Then you can simply pick the records that have `row_number=2` to get the closest record to the max `created_date`.

```sql
SELECT servicecalls_servicecall_id,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by servicecalls_servicecall_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS row_number
FROM service_followup_details 
WHERE servicecalls_servicecall_id IN (
  SELECT service_call_id FROM service_calls WHERE status=2
) 
AND row_number = 2;
```